# How to sort my doctrine result by number of associated entities and limit by timespan

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, count, one-to-many

I have two entities, `Class` and `Student`. One `Class` can have multiple `Student`s, so it's a oneToMany relation. (Don't bother, that it should be a manyToMany relationship, I'm just drawing an example.)

```
# YAML notation for Entity 'Class'
...
oneToMany:
    students:
        targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\Student
        mappedBy: class

# YAML notation for Entity 'Student'
...
date: datetime # this is the date where Student joined a Class
```

For fetching all `Class`es, I'm writing my own query like this:

```
SELECT c
FROM MyBundle:Class c
WHERE c.whatever = :parameter
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

Now I'm trying to fetch a list of "rising" `Class`es. That means, that all `Class`es, that have been joined by `Student`s within the last five days - ordered (DESC) by the number of joined `Student`s.

So that the result would look like:

```
Class.id   Class.count(Student)   Latest Join
--------   --------------------   -----------
       3                     19    2013-12-07
       1                     12    2013-12-08
       4                      8    2013-12-07
       2                      5    2013-12-09
```

How would I go there? I tried something somewhat like this:

```
SELECT
    c,
    COUNT(c.students) AS students,
    MAX(s.date)
FROM MyBundle:Class c
WHERE c.whatever = :param
AND DATE(s.date) > :fivedayspan
ORDER BY students DESC
```

(Note: I implement [DoctrineExtensions' Date](https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions) function)

I am setting the parameter:

```
$q->setParameter('fivedayspan', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 days')));
```

But I'm getting an error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 36 near 'students)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Comment: Are you looking for a DQL or QueryBuilder solution here? Btw there is no **`DATE`** function in DQL ... see **[DQL Functions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)** :)

Comment: Rather DQL than  qb, but I'm fine with both. And: I can use date (and I'm already succesfully using it) by using the DoctrineExtensions.

Answer (score -1):

Will this work?

```
SELECT
    c,
    COUNT(c.students) AS c.N,
    MAX(c.date)
FROM MyBundle:Class c
WHERE c.whatever = :param
AND DATE(c.date) > :fivedayspan
ORDER BY c.N DESC
```

Comment: This will not work ... and there is no DATE function in DQL. Sorry :)

Comment: Nevermind, I'm using the DoctrineExtensions. I'll try this one out!